# How to store every network request into an array given the loop behaviour of request.continue()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I'm trying to get all the network requests when a page is accessed and store them into an array.

My code looks like this:

```
  await page.setRequestInterceptionEnabled(true);
  page.on('request', request => {
      if(request.url) {
          var networkRequests = request.url;
          var networkArray = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < networkRequests; i++) {
              networkArray.push(networkRequests[i]);
          }
          console.log(networkArray);
          console.log(typeof networkArray);
          request.continue();
      } else {
          request.abort();
      }

  });
  await page.goto('http://www.example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
```

I find that the problem is with the `request.continue()`. It creates several iterations for each fetched request, and for each iteration it shows that request and returns it as string.
That means that I end up with several strings.

The problem is that I couldn't managed to insert all those strings into one array, so I can make use of them lately. I tried several for loops but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix has been found in the meantime:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function extractRequests(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        (async() => {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.setRequestInterceptionEnabled(true);
            let result = [];
            page.on('request', request => {
                if (request.url) {
                    var networkRequests = request.url;
                    result.push(networkRequests);
                    request.continue();
                } else {
                    request.abort();
                }

            });
            page.goto(url, {
                     waitUntil: 'networkidle'
                })
                .then( _=> setTimeout( _=> resolve(result), 1000));
        })();
    });
}

extractRequests('http://example.com').then(requests => {
    console.log(requests.filter(x => x.includes('event-name') && x.includes('other-event-name')));
    process.exit(0);
});
```